# To apply quotient rule to show that show that $f'(0)=p'(0)/q(0)$ if $p(0)=0$

Tags: derivatives

I am asked to apply the quotient rule 
$$f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$ and show that 
$$f'(0)=\frac{p'(0)}{q(0)}$$ if $p(0)=0$, and hence evaluate $f'(0)$  where 
$$f(x)=\frac{xe^{2x}}{(2-x)(1-x)^2}$$ ...dont get it...just replace all $x$'s by $0$?? I don't get what they ask me to show then...:S

Comment: Please check my edit. I hope this is correct.

Comment: Note that you need the condition $q(0)\neq 0$ for this to be true. It holds for your example. You can't just replace all $x$'s by $0$, you need to compute $p'$ first.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = p(x)/q(x)$, then $f'(x) = \frac{p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)}{q^2(x)}$.

If $p(0) = 0$, then $f'(0) = \frac{p'(0)q(0)-0\cdot q'(0)}{q^2(0)}$.

You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient rule tells you that
$$f'(x) = \frac{p'(x)}{q(x)} - \frac{p(x)q'(x)}{q(x)^2}.$$

If $p(0) = 0$ and $q(0) \neq 0$, what is $f'(0)$?

The second part is just putting this principle into practice for a concrete example.